# How to get all the docs from a subcollection in Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a structure like this:

```
A (collection): {a (doc): {B (collection): {b (doc)}}}
```

I need to get the "b" from all the "a".

I don't need the relation between them, I only need all the "b".

I'm working in Android Studio with Java.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the documents in a subcollection, just build a path to it using the names of the collections and documents you know, and use `get()` to [fetch the results](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), [just like any other Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries):

```
Query q = firestore.collection("A").document("a").collection("B");
q.get() // add listeners for the results
```